# How to decode an unsigned transaction using polkadot.js

Tags: polkadot-js, scale-codec

If I have some unsigned transaction, eg `0x040300865ea...` and I wanted to decode it into a format like:

```
method: "balances",
section: "transfer":
...
```

Is there a way to do that using polkadot.js or similar library? Most of the information I've come across describes the SCALE codec itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The api provides a shortcut helper for this - `api.tx(<hex bytes>)` will decode/reconstruct it.